# Flash PreloadSwf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

When i try to load an external swf file using
Loader.Load();

The swf starts playing even before the init event is fired. Is there any way to stop the swf from playing atleast until the init event or complete event is fired?

Comment: Hard to say without more details, but if the swf you load has a timeline, you need to stop() it at the first frame, or it will start to play frames as they are loaded.

Comment: Even if i add loader to the stage. The stage of the child is null which confuses me !

Answer (score 0):

You may use an `URLLoader` to get your swf instead. When it dispatches the INIT event, you can retrieve its content. Then just load it in a `Loader` with `myLoader.loadBytes(myUrlLoader.data as ByteArray)`. The loaded swf will only start playing then.